# C++ goto statement execute without calling

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make a simple code demonstrating the benefits of Goto statements.

i put the goto label; inside an if statement :

```
 int x;
   cin>>x;

   if (x == 10){
      goto win;
   }else{
      cout<<"its not a 10";
   }

   win: cout<<"you win";
```

the problem occurs when x is anything but 10, its if 9 then it will display
its not a 10you win

i've tried to put the win: cout<<"you win"; before the if statement and still the same problem.

Comment: This example doesn't showcase any benefits.

Comment: @Cygwinnian i've come to the same realization, thank you

Comment: @ollieford, the mockery isn't appreciated, i'm a beginner studying for a C++ final exam, thank you for stopping by.

Comment: Maybe it is the phrasing of your question. If you set out to demonstrate the benefits of X, it would be assumed that you have some understanding of X.

Comment: I'm a beginner too. But as @juanchopanza says, you say you're trying to demonstrate benefits - a quick search would have revealed advice almost unanimously against the use of `goto` in this and more complex examples. I've never seen a use that couldn't better be implemented with a function call, or inside some loop. I'm sorry to sound like I was mocking you - but it honestly reads like a troll post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `x` is not equal to `10`, then the `else` block will occur. Control will then continue to flow onwards until it reaches `cout<<"you win"`. Just because there's a label before that `cout`, doesn't mean it'll only happen if you do `goto win;`. It's still part of the control flow of the function.

This is simply not an appropriate use of `goto` (not even arguably). You should just do:

```
if (x == 10){
   cout<<"you win";
}else{
   cout<<"its not a 10";
}
```

If you really wanted to move the `cout<<"you win"` to another block of code, you would need to put it in its own function:

```
void print_win() {
  cout<<"you win";
}
```

and then do `print_win();` in the first `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

This is code that demonstrates the errors you make with goto statements: Control flow is transferred to a point that is reached in one flow of logic (x==10) and in all other cases, too.

It's very difficult to demonstrate the *benefits* of a goto statement. You'll have to come up with a logic that isn't an if, or a switch.

Comment: Or a while. Or better implemented by a function.

Comment: @Ollie Ford Or a for. Or a do. Or a continue. Or a break. Or a better algorithm. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code example demonstrates that goto statement has no any benefits;

It contains a logic error because the control independing of the value of x will achieve label win. So it always will display

```
you win
```

The code would be much better if it had no goto statement. For example

```
int x;
cin >> x;

if ( x == 10 )
{
   cout << "you win";
}
else
{
   cout << "its not a 10";
}
```